# How to cache Aws HTTP request result using browser built-in cache?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

Caching request is a feature provided by browser itself. You can find the document here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache

```
// Download a resource with cache busting, to bypass the cache
// completely.
fetch("some.json", {cache: "no-store"})
  .then(function(response) { /* consume the response */ });

// Download a resource with cache busting, but update the HTTP
// cache with the downloaded resource.
fetch("some.json", {cache: "reload"})
  .then(function(response) { /* consume the response */ });
```

Is there a way to use browser built-in cache feature to cache Javascript AWS SDK result in browser?

For example, I want to use above MDN request object to cache the following AWS SDK api request:

```
    // Function invoked by button click
    function speakText() {
        // Create the JSON parameters for getSynthesizeSpeechUrl
        var speechParams = {
            OutputFormat: "mp3",
            SampleRate: "16000",
            Text: "",
            TextType: "text",
            VoiceId: "Matthew"
        };

        // Create the Polly service object and presigner object
        var polly = new AWS.Polly({apiVersion: '2016-06-10'});
        var signer = new AWS.Polly.Presigner(speechParams, polly)
    
        // Create presigned URL of synthesized speech file
        signer.getSynthesizeSpeechUrl(speechParams, function(error, url) {
        if (error) {
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = error;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('audioSource').src = url;
            document.getElementById('audioPlayback').load();
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Speech ready to play.";
        }
      });
    }
```

You can find the above code in [AWS official tutorial here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-browser.html).

Answer (score 1):

That code creates pre-signed URLs. The URLs will be different each time. Browsers identify cached objects by URL, so in this scenario a browser would never utilize the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The browser follow the cache headers to knows if it can cache it or not. If the cache header say to not cache, it wont cache it.
Anyway, i dont think it make sense to cache a signed url. It will expires.

You can still do the aws stuff on a backend and return the audio file with the good cache headers.